# How to add "-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug" JVM option to android project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-debug

According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#debugging-using-logging) we can add `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` JVM option to debug Kotlin coroutines. How to do it for Android project in Android Studio?

Comment: Hi, do you have an answer now?

Comment: Hi, no I don't, sorry.

Comment: I found a related [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-575/Coroutine-debugger-doesnt-work-in-Android-project) about this problem, Seems like this is a long backlog issue.